# Jquery toggle function problem with checkbox if else statement

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery toggle function. I have made an if else statment to fix the bug when a checkbox i pressed directly its got checked and uncheched. Therefor I have maded a else if statement to check if the checkbox have been checked. But now the checkbox does not even get checked onclick.

Here it is live: http://jsfiddle.net/mvdnj/14/

My Jquery:

```
categoryDiv.toggle(function () {
    relativeMinimenu.removeClass('hidediv').addClass('someclass').show(200);
    categoryDiv.addClass('clicked').show(200);

    if(   categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked') ) { 
        categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    } else{
        categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
}
, function () {
    categoryDiv.removeClass('clicked').find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
    relativeMinimenu.addClass('hidediv');
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top: 81px; width: 200px; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);" cxlass="searchbox">  
<form method="get" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"></div>

        <div id="category" class="menuitem category clicked">
                <label id="search_Company1_is_true" for="search_Company1">Company1 </label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[Company1_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[Company1_is_true]" id="search_Company1_is_true" checked="checked">
        <div class="counter">1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="minimenu" class="someclass">
        <div class="miniitem">
         <label for="search_feature1">feature1</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[feature1_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[feature1_is_true]" id="search_feature1_is_true">
        </div>         <div class="miniitem">
         <label for="search_feature1">feature1</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[feature1_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[feature1_is_true]" id="search_feature1_is_true">
        </div>         <div class="miniitem">
         <label for="search_feature1">feature1</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[feature1_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[feature1_is_true]" id="search_feature1_is_true">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem category clicked">
        <label for="search_company2">company2</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="search[company2_is_true]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="search[company2_is_true]" id="search_company2_is_true" checked="checked">
        <div class="counter">1</div>
        </div>
 <div class="someclass">
        <div class="menuitem">
        </div>
</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display: none;" name="commit" id="search_submit" class="sdasd">

</form></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And my suggestion - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/2/)

Basically much lighter HTML and jQuery code. I did strip off alot of the CSS, so you could re-add that later.

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="checkGroup">
        <label>
            <span>Company1</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section" value="1"/>
        </label>
        <div class="payload">
            <label>
                <span>Feature1</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="1"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Feature2</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="2"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Feature3</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="3"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkGroup">
        <label>
            <span>Company2</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="section" value="1"/>
        </label>
        <div class="payload">
            <label>
                <span>Feature1</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="1"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Feature2</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="2"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Feature3</span>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="3"/>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.payload').hide();

    $('.checkGroup > label > input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
        $t = $(this);
        $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload').toggle( $t.is(':checked') );
        if( !$t.is(':checked') ){
           $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload input[type="checkbox"]')
               .attr('checked',false);
        }
    }).trigger('change');

});
```

If you are wanting to have Counters showing how many checkboxes in each group are checked, then use the following Javascript / jQuery - [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/10/)

```
$('.payload').hide();

$('.checkGroup > label > input[type="checkbox"]').live('change',function(){
    $t = $(this);
    $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload').toggle( $t.is(':checked') );
    if( !$t.is(':checked') ){
       $t.closest('.checkGroup').find('.payload input[type="checkbox"]')
           .attr('checked',false);
    }
}).trigger('change');


$('.checkGroup input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
   $c = $(this);
   $c.closest('.checkGroup').find('label > span b').text( $c.closest('.checkGroup').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length );
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I have tried to add the checkbox counter as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/GAZqG/5/, but the hole menu unfolds: http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/9/

Comment: Always, where possible, apply the KISS Principle to code - http://jsfiddle.net/mtYtW/10/

Comment: Why is there no payload.show()? Is it the toggle function that does th show() ?

Answer (score 1):

My proposition: http://jsfiddle.net/GAZqG/3/

You have one error:

```
if(   categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked') )
```

should be:

```
if(   categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked') == 'checked' )
```

or

```
if(   categoryDiv.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked')  )
```

Comment: How do I implement the each function to your solution and how do I get it to like http://jsfiddle.net/mvdnj/3/ where it is not unfolded. Nice that the checkbox counter works as wanted, just it only counts if the maincategory is clicked

Comment: I have tried to hide the subcategory, but now it does take 2 click to onfold http://jsfiddle.net/GAZqG/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/GAZqG/13/ - i've unchecked category checkbox and updated code on start by triggering click

Comment: Thanks I think I would take the more lightweight solution, I just need to figure out how to implement the checkbox counter :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/mvdnj/21/

The JQuery is:

```
$('form').delegate('.category', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this), $menu = $this.next(), $cb = $('input:checkbox', $this);
    $cb.attr('checked', $menu.css('display') == 'none');
    $menu.toggle();
});

$('form').delegate('.someclass input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
    var $menu = $(this).parents('.someclass'), $cat = $menu.prev();
    var count = $("input:checkbox:checked", $menu).length;
    $('.counter', $cat).text(count);
});
```

This uses the JQuery [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method which is more efficient, creating only two event handlers - one for div click and menu toggle, and one to handle the checkbox counter. Here I have attached the handlers to your only form, since that contains all the relevant divs, but you don't have to, and you could use e.g. 'body' if you prefer.

Comment: @Rails beginner - huh? works fine here - what do you mean 'nothing works'?